# How to create Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to create a test database using the Entity framework and code-first. I just want this new database to be the same as my old database data. Can you help me with this?

For example;

- Old database name: TEST
- Old database tables: Person, Country, Student

`Person` columns:

```
ID, Name, Surname, Job
```

`Country` columns:

```
CountryID, CountryName
```

`Student` columns:

```
StudentID, StudentName, StudentSurname
```

I want to create a new database `TEST2` and  I want to create a transport of the test database.

- New database name: TEST2
- New database tables: Person, Country, Student - all with the identical columns as in the old database

**PersonEntities.cs**:

```
public partial class PersonEntities : DbContext 
{ 
    public PersonEntities() : base()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can try change the name of database on stringConnection, or you can have two connectionString and use a DEBUG configuration for use one of these.

Comment: You never state a problem or ask a question. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*